# Why does IE cause a bad request?

Tags: ssl

I have setup SSL on the domain. It works fine on Chrome ,Firefox, and Safari. However, for IEs, it returns

"Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. 
Client sent malformed Host header"

Any idea why?

Comment: what versions of IE? And what is in the web server's log files?

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being me not providing the intermediate.

Chrome: try to download it using known servers. works fine.

Firefox: gives warning.

IE: tries to download it from the server, server gives error.